# Specific Quote Issue

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Here is my problem.  I have a model Project, that has a quote field in it. When a new instance of project is created I need to append the last 2 digits of the year plus a hyphen onto the start of the "quote" field. Ex. 2010 = "10-".  Im just not quite sure how to start it?

As of right now I have hard coded in "10-" in as a pre-quote field, but I do not want to have to do that.

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
client = models.ForeignKey(Clients, related_name='projects')
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_by')


#general information
proj_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Project Name')
pre_quote = models.CharField(max_length=3,default='10-')
quote = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Quote #', unique=True)
desc = models.TextField(verbose_name='Description')
starts_on = models.DateField(verbose_name='Start Date')
completed_on = models.DateField(verbose_name='Finished On')
```

Anyone have to do this before?  Or have any suggestions?

Comment: Re: "When a new instance of project is created I need to append the last 2 digits of the year plus a hyphen onto the start of the "quote" field." You don't need to do that. If you want that for the purposes of display, do that at the time you display. If it is for searching, then add the year of the quote to your database search. Either way, there is no need to add this data to your quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def save(self):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    self.quote = "%s-%s" % (str(today.year)[2:4], self.quote)
```

Assuming you imported datetime.

Comment: I have imported datetime, but it is giving me this error: AttributeError at /project/add/

'module' object has no attribute 'now'

Comment: Sorry for that, forgot `.date` in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing quote field is set as an integer.  You will need to set this as a text field.  Once you do that, you can override the save() function to prepend "10-" to the field.

```
class Project(models.Model):
  client = models.ForeignKey(Clients, related_name='projects')
  created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_by')
  proj_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Project Name')
  quote = models.TextField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Quote #', unique=True)
  desc = models.TextField(verbose_name='Description')
  starts_on = models.DateField(verbose_name='Start Date')
  completed_on = models.DateField(verbose_name='Finished On')

  def save(self):
    self.quote = "10-" + self.quote
```

Comment: I tried this, but when upon saving from form submit, I was presented with this:
TypeError at /project/add/

save() takes no arguments (1 given)